Cannot install Ubuntu Studio from USB live stick (24.04 LTS Noble Numbat) on ASUS Vivo AiO V221IC
I downloaded https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/noble/release/ubuntustudio-24.04.1-dvd-amd64.iso, checked the checksum was correct and created a bootable USB stick using Rufus.
I modified the BIOS of my PC (ASUS Vivo AiO V221IC-UKBA020D, BIOS version updated with the last version, dating back to 2018) to boot from USB.
The PC boots from USB and shows the bootloader options. I chose the first one, something like "run and install Ubuntu". I can see the splash screen with both ASUS and Ubuntu Studio logos and the rolling wheel.
After some minutes of that, the screen gets completely black with one line saying:

[FAILED] Failed to start snapd.service - Snap Daemon.

I made some searches and apparently Ubuntu 24.04 installer is a new one and it's still quite unstable.
Do you know how to solve the problem?
Is there another way of installing Ubuntu Studio?
Would it be possible to install an older release (not using the new installer) and then upgrading to 24.04? If so, which one would you suggest?
Thanks.
Ciao,
Max
UPDATE: I created the bootable USB stick starting from Ubuntu Studio 22.04.05 and it worked. There must be something in 24.04 conflicting with my PC. Now I just have to update it to 24.04...

Try this:
Start a live session of Ubuntu Studio.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted
From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a new gpt partition table.
In the free space, create a 512-megabyte partition, Efi-Boot partition (Fat32).
Next, create a 80-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 16-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes, close gparted, close the terminal, start the installation.
Choose manual partitioning
Select Grub on the hard drive
The 80-gigabyte partition for /
The 16-gigabyte partition for swap
The remaining one for /home.
Continue with the installation.
